# someone is proxying to my server

Tags: nginx, centos, cloudflare

I have very big problem some Russian guy or guys is proxying to my server which effected my Google ranks, I tried blocking the IP but he's connecting from to many IPs so I tried blocking countries he used like Russia and Poland but there are many countries to block...

Right now my website domain is **example.com**, and his domain name is **bad-example.com**, if you access his website you will find the some content my website has, and if I update anything on my website it updates on his website also, if I stop Nginx from my server his website is also stopped.

So I think he's proxying to my server. 
**Is there any way to accept proxy request only from CloudFlare and block the rest?**

I'm using Nginx and CloudFlare for my server.

Comment: Configure the firewall on your server to accept  incoming connection only from CloudFlare

Comment: https://www.leowkahman.com/2016/05/02/automate-raspberry-pi-ufw-allow-cloudflare-inbound/

Comment: i already tried that , but the problem is the bad guy website is also behind cloudflare :(

Comment: Can't believe that outgoing traffic from a CloudFlare protected site would be from one of CloudFlare's IP addresses.

Comment: no one has any solution  ?

Answer (score 0):

This happened to one of my websites and below settings helped me resolve it.

Check the IP of bad-example.com. If it is the same IP of yours then bad-example.com is using a CNAME kind of technique that points to your IP. So everything on your website will appear on the bad-example.com website as well. It does not mean that your server is compromised. But it can be very costly for SEO.

If you are using a default host in your server rather than virtual hosts, there is a high chance of this happening.

One simple way is to check for a HOST header in the HTTP request and add a condition in the .htaccess file to redirect the request to your website or any other page you like.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bad-example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.bad-example\.com 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://google.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Or you can only server the content to known HOSTS only.